# What is the proper behavior of 'jalr $a0, $a0'?

Tags: mips, mips32, spim, mars-simulator

I came across the instruction `jalr $t1, $t2` instruction, which supposedly sets $t1 to the return address and jumps to $t2. However, there seems to be some ambiguity as to which operation happens first. For instance, the following works differently in MARS and SPIM:

```
.text
main:
    la $t0, func
    jalr $t0, $t0
    # ...
    li $v0, 10
    syscall        # Exit program

func:
    # ...
    jr $t0
```

In MARS, `$t0` is first set to `pc + 4` (return address) and then jumps to `$t0`, so that the code under `func` is never run. However, SPIM seems to do the oppsite: jump first and then set the value of `$t0` to (the previous) `pc + 4`; thus `func` is called and runs as usual.

My question is therefore, which simulator implements correct behavior in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Imagination Technologies' `The MIPS32® Instruction Set v5.03` with emphasis added for clarity ([registration required for download of the whole document](http://www.imgtec.com/mips/mips32-architecture.asp))

```
Format: JALR rs (rd = 31 implied)  
        JALR rd, rs
```

> Restrictions:
>
> ***Register specifiers rs and rd must not be equal***, because such an instruction does not have the same effect when reexecuted. ***The result of executing such an instruction is UNPREDICTABLE.*** This restriction permits an exception handler to resume execution by re-executing the branch when an exception occurs in the branch delay slot.
>   ))

In other words, they're strangely enough both correct.

Answer (score 1):

The [MIPS instruction spec](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2013sp/MIPS_Vol2.pdf) says:

```
Operation:
    I:  temp ← GPR[rs]
        GPR[rd] ← PC + 8
    I+1:if Config1CA = 0 then
            PC ← temp
        else
            PC ← temp<sub>GPRLEN-1..1</sub> || 0
            ISAMode ← temp<sub>0</sub>
        endif
```

So it would seem that SPIM is correct and MARS is wrong.